# Not seeing First Posts - is it because I often skip?

Tags: support, review-queues, first-post-review

I like to look through the First Posts review to look for questions I can actually help improve. I tend to err strongly on the side of skipping when I don't know, which is often: if there is a question about Java I probably wouldn't be able to tell if the code is gibberish so I'm better off leaving it alone. In the last couple of weeks I have noticed the review is always empty for me, even when I see posts by new users on the front page. I was wondering if the system was set up to show me fewer and fewer posts because I usually skip?

Comment: The FP queue is there to show you posts that you can improve, or use other moderation tools to deal with problematic content.  It's not there to show you thinks for you to answer.  In fact, the queue is *designed* to show you things that you probably *can't* answer.  If you're looking for questions to answer, you should be using the homepage, or the questions list, or search, or other tools designed to show you questions suitable for being answered.

Comment: Okay - I suppose I should have written that a bit differently. I also use FP for its intended purpose (flagging, editing, commenting, giving the thumbs up and moving on) but my point of posting is that because I don't know what a lot of posts need (I cannot tell if a Java post that looks okay, actually isn't just garbage) I skip a lot. I don't think this is an abuse since I'm interacting with it partly for fun and to help as much as I can without hurting the site. I was just wondering if the queue is actually empty or if SO is set up to prevent people lurking as I do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First question: you haven't set up a filter by accident?

[image]

> I was wondering if the system was set up to show me fewer and fewer posts because I usually skip?

Nope. Only posts which you already acted on aren't shown in the review queue.

> In the last couple of weeks I have noticed the review is always empty for me, even when I see posts by new users on the front page.

It takes a couple of minutes for posts to get into the First Post review queue. Also, other people who are reviewing might get to those posts before you do.

Comment: Filter isn't on, but that's a good thing to be aware of that I wasn't. I guess people are just on top of their game, which is great. Thanks :)

Comment: @HFBrowning get to 3k rep and you'll never be short of things to review in the close vote queue :)

Comment: ...or get a diamond next to your name.